# React onChange event fires empty string on first input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Problem - There is no string output the very first time I type in text. This is causing the last character of whatever I enter into the output to not appear. Why is this?

Some state - Focusing on `name` property

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState({
    name: '',
    signOff: ''
});
```

**Input**

```
<input
 type="text"
 placeholder="Enter first name"
 name="name"
 id="name"
 onChange={(e) => handleNameChange(e.target.value)}
/>
```

**Function to fire after input change**

```
const handleNameChange = (name: string) => {
    setOptions({
        ...options,
        name
    });
    console.log(options);
};
```

**Example console output after typing "hello"** - Why the empty string for `name` property?

```
{name: '', signOff: ''}       options.tsx:17 
{name: 'h', signOff: ''}      options.tsx:17 
{name: 'he', signOff: ''}     options.tsx:17 
{name: 'hel', signOff: ''}    options.tsx:17 
{name: 'hell', signOff: ''}   options.tsx:17
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its expected behaviour, because setStates are asynchronous, so when you log the state variable immediately after its being set, it logs previous value, not the updated one
If you just want to log the state changes, move `console.log()` to `useEffect` hook

```
const handleNameChange = (name: string) => {
    setOptions({
        ...options,
        name
    });
    console.log(options);
};
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(options);
}, [options]);
```

Comment: problem is....I'n trying to store this data in `localstorage`. Guess I will need to set this within `useEffect()` call? ideally I wanted to fetch from local storage. perhaps i can have two useEffects() one without dependency to just fetch from localstorage and another with dependencies and to watch for changes?

Comment: @Samuel, yes - useEffect without dependency will give initial value to your options state when component mounts... after that its wise to use useEffect with required dependency for any state change related operations

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it and I haven't encountered any such problem.
You can also use the same function for every other input, not just name.

```
<input
 type="text"
 placeholder="Enter first name"
 name="name"
 id="name"
 onChange={handleChange}
/>

const handleChange = (e) => {
    setOptions({
        ...options,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add options variable as the second parameter to useEffect. This means that in every state change of this variable this function will be fired.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(options);
}, [options]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In React, setState is not performed immediately, instead it gets scheduled. This is an asynchronous operation.
You are logging the state value immediately after `setOptions` call. So, as soon as `setOptions` get scheduled, the JS engine moves to next line i.e. `console.log`. That's why, such o/p gets logged.

Instead you can log state value just before `return()`. You'll see the correct state values. Or, you can simply wrap it in some JSX tag in return() statement and test.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-usestateref` npm

```
const [options, setOptions, optionsRef] = useState({
    name: "",
    signOff: ""
  });




  const handleNameChange = (text) => {
    setOptions({
      ...options,
      name: text
    });
    console.log(optionsRef.current);
  };
```

[react-usestateref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-usestateref)

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-tdd-4hn9ur?file=/src/App.js:192-330)